# Quiet installation of MS SQL 2012 RC0 from command line using config file

Tags: sql-server-2012

My problem is that I recently deployed Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 Express to create a database for a locally hosted application to access.  To save myself time I used the /CONFIGURATIONFILE option to set it all up to run from the command line so I could stript the installation from soup to nuts.

I now am trying to use the same ini file with Micro SQL Server 2012 RC0 and the thing won't install quietly.  I continually get the Window to configure installation even if I use /Q="true", /QS="true", and I even tried /QUIET="true" but the window continues to open.

Is there a way to force MS SQL Server 2012 RC0 to install quietly or is that functionality that is not in this release?

Answer (score 2):

Have you specified the rest of the required command line parameters for a quiet install for instance IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS?

This [help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) covers the required parameters for a quiet command line install.

Comment: Call setup.exe with your configuration file and "/q" and in the configuration file use INDICATEPROGRESS="False"